# Activity on top of all windows

Tags: java, android, sdk

How can I make a button, text or panel appear on top of other windows after minimizing the application?  I have seen this feature in many autoclickers and similar applications.

How to create an activity on top of all windows?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.